# Safe Contract Without Nonce

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature, safe-core-sdk, safe

Is it possible to modify the Safe contracts by removing the nonce parameter and executing a transaction. I am trying to do this but i am stuck on the signature part .It's giving me signature error . I am creating signature using the script provided in the [safe-smart account](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/tree/main).and facing  `GS026` which means the decoded address from signature is not the owner. If its possible can anyone tell me how can i create the right signature

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended, as nonces are used to protect your contracts against replay attacks. Removing them would mean that anyone could resubmit the same transaction again and, for example, drain your safe.

If you still choose to do so, we won't be able to support you as we prioritize standard ("official") contract implementations and we can't be accountable for the behavior of a contract where major security features are disabled.

One last thing is that if you are using non-standard contracts, any interaction with our services (API, Transaction Service and overall infrastructure) as well as using our SDK or CLI won't be possible.

So again I can not stress enough that we highly advise against doing this.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis